# How to Map Firebase Database?

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

**Hi all,**

In my **React.js** application, I have a **component X**, where I want to return a `map()` that iterates through my **Firebase Realtime Database** ref "lang".

But I keep on getting: "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])".

My code looks like this:

```
export default function X () {
    const mapped = firebase.database().ref('lang').once('value', function (snap) {
        snap.map(snap =>
                <button>
                {snap.key}
            </button>
        )
    })
    return (
        <article>
            {mapped}
        </article>
    )
}
```

How can I fix this?

**THANKS!!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)  You've got a Promise (as the error says) so you need to await/then the response before trying to render it in JSX.

Comment: It's not really a good idea to put async work immediately in your render function.  Typically you use a useEffect hook or some other mechanism to get your component to re-render after the async work is complete.